# How to use a JTextPanel to get a string

Tags: java, input, jtextfield, bufferedreader, keylistener

I need to get an input from keyboard using a JtextPanel, saving it on a string when I press enter, then use that string to do some action based on line given in input ( example "help" or "quit"). I got this in my KeyListener for JTextPanel:

```
...
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
     int key = e.getKeyCode();    

     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        inputString = textField.getText();
        textArea.append(inputString + "\n");
        textField.setText("");

        }
}
....
```

, but I cant call this method directly. I would need something like

```
String input = processInput();
    if((input).equals("help"))
          ............
    else if ((input).equals("go"))
          ............
```

and processInput should be a method that waits for the (key== KeyEvent.VK_ENTER), like happens when you use the scanf in C or the bufferedReader in java, it waits for you giving a string from keyboard till you press enter.
EDIT

My app manages commands like that

```
while(!finished) {

    finished = processInput() 
}
```

processInput manages the command given in input. That's why I cant call processInput() from the keyListener
I hope i was clear, my english is so bad!

thanks

Comment: Just call `processInput(inputString);` when you press the Enter key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this approach, pretty simple.

KeyListener:

```
...
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
     int key = e.getKeyCode();    

     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        inputString = textField.getText();
        textArea.append(inputString + "\n");
        textField.setText("");
        processInput(inputString); //crunch it
        }
}
....
```

And elsewhere

```
public void processInput(String input) {
    if((input).equals("help"))
          ............
    else if ((input).equals("go"))
          ............
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are stuck on the architectural design of an event-driven interface.

The idea here is that you don't go "waiting" for input or whatever.  You set up the interface, attach the KeyListener (you do have an `addKeyListener()` somewhere, right...), and then you're done.  You give up control flow, let your main method end, done.

When the user does something noteworthy, you then deal with it, so say you had a method `processText(String text)`, you would, in your keylistener there, say `processText(inputString);`.

Thus, when the user enters something and hits enter, it starts executing in the keyListener, which passes control flow into the `processText()` method, which would do whatever it should do because of that text.